# WSO2 APIM Setup

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I followed the tutorial here:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics+Using+WSO2+DAS#PublishingAPIRuntimeStatisticsUsingWSO2DAS-ConfiguringWSO2APIManager

On configuring WSO2 API Manager, I cannot seem to configure Analytics when I am inside the Admin Portal. Is there some configuration first that needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at APIM 1.9.1 documentation. But it looks like you are using latest APIM which is 2.0.0. In 2.0.0 you can configure analytics in `api-manager.xml` only. See [APIM 2.0.0 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics).

One important thing about APIM 2.0.0 is, you don't need to configure DAS from scratch. Now DAS is pre-configured with required CApps and shipped as `wso2am-analytics-2.0.0.zip`. You can download it from [APIM Product page](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/) itself.